# iOS game center -- frequent CONNECTION INTERRUPTED messages

Tags: ios, connection, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I am working on an iOS game center game, using GKTurnBasedMatch.  Every time an incomplete turn, there is a message in the console like this:

```
2013-04-26 19:26:45.115 AppName[6439:5a9f] CONNECTION INTERRUPTED
```

Interestingly, this does not happen when I send a complete turn with

```
[match endTurnWithNextParticipants: nextParticipants turnTimeout:100000 matchData: data completionHandler:^(NSError* error){
    // some block here
}];
```

but it does happen when I send an incomplete turn with

```
[match saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:^(NSError* error) {
     // some block here
}];
```

Someone else reported a similar problem here: [Spurious Game Center player disconnect messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051564/spurious-game-center-player-disconnect-messages).  However, it is difficult to see how the only answer there applies to my situation, as I am creating my matches with GKMatchmakerViewController.

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm experiencing the same problem. I used saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData to save some randomized elements of my board game immediately after creating a new game, but I had to remove it because of the disconnect issue.

Comment: @Bart -- Don't remember, sorry